# how to use 2 loops on th using v-for on vue.js?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, loops, v-for

I have a table like this the code, but I have to repeat it 6 times to match the day column above it and I want to do it with v-for. and I have a variable "count" number of days if you want to use it. So can someone help me?

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" rowspan="2">Dosen</th>
            <th scope="col" colspan="11" v-for="(hari, index) in hari" :key="index">{{hari.nama}}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" colspan="1" v-for="jam in jam" :key="jam">{{jam.kode}}</th>
            <th scope="col" colspan="1" v-for="jam in jam" :key="jam">{{jam.kode}}</th>
            <th scope="col" colspan="1" v-for="jam in jam" :key="jam">{{jam.kode}}</th>
            <th scope="col" colspan="1" v-for="jam in jam" :key="jam">{{jam.kode}}</th>
            <th scope="col" colspan="1" v-for="jam in jam" :key="jam">{{jam.kode}}</th>
            <th scope="col" colspan="1" v-for="jam in jam" :key="jam">{{jam.kode}}</th>
        </tr>    
    </thead>  
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(dosen, index) in dosen" :key="index">
            <th scope="row">{{dosen.nama}}</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>  
</table>
```

The expected table:

[image: table]

> this is the script for my data:

```
 <script>
onMounted(() =>{
    if(!token) {
        return router.push({
        name: 'Login'
        })
    }

    //get hari
    axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/hari')
    .then(response => {
    //assign state posts with response data
    hari.value = response.data.data         
    count.value = response.data.count
    // console.log(count)
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error.response.data)
    })

    //get jam
    axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/jam')
    .then(response => {
    //assign state posts with response data
    jam.value = response.data.data         
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error.response.data)
    })

    //get dosen
    axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/dosen')
    .then(response => {
    //assign state posts with response data
    dosen.value = response.data.data         
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error.response.data)
    })
})
```

Comment: Can you show us your `data`? Including the value for the `jam` variable?

Comment: sure, clock is the data i fetched from the database via axios like this  axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
        axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/jam')
        .then(response => {
        //assign state posts with response data
        jam.value = response.data.data         
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error.response.data)
        })

Comment: without actual example data (to see exactly what it looks like) it's impossible to answer you ... *how* you get the data is irrelevant, what the data *is* is the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this fit your need ?

```
<template v-for="i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]" :key="i">
  <th scope="col" colspan="1" v-for="jam in jam" :key="jam">{{jam.kode}}</th>
</template>
```

Comment: it will loop on parent th (tr), i need loop 6 times on th, but still thanks

Comment: the parent of <th> is <template> here, so it will render to six times the inner th element. Try it !